# Decoding blob data from a sqlite database into a human readable text

Tags: java, sqlite, blob

I have a Sqlite database file that has blob data in it. 
I only know the the database has blob data and I know what the expected output should be.
The blob data's expected output should be a Mac address with other text.

I tried getting the hex output but does not really help me with getting the expected output that I know is in the database. I also used a Hex editor and sqlite viewer but only shows gibberish unreadable text.

Here is some code that I tried to get the bytes from the blob data but does not produce the output I expected. Sqlite doesn't have the getBlob function in Java.

```
if (rs.next()) {
    byte[] buffer = rs.getBytes(1);
    System.out.println(buffer.toString());
}
```

An expected output from the blob should be :" JOHN A6:44:33:A4:G5:A4 "

Here is a sample Hex dump 0008f473eb41
e8ba3b1c

How can I programattically retrieve the blob data and decode the contents of the blob in sqlite?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are printing a `byte[]` array `toString()`. Arrays in Java don't implement in meaningful way.

You can try converting the `byte[]` array into a `String` with:

```
new String(buffer, Charsets.UTF_8)
```

If this doesn't work use `rs.getBinaryStream(1)` to get the `InputStream` representing the value and read it as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/309448/1602555).

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but the output is still the same : This is the output from converting to string –v$%^KJ%^³‚W *Ôô

Comment: If you don't show how the value is stored I can only guess how to read it.

Comment: Yeah, I am reverse engineering and don't know how the value is stored. If I knew how it was stored, it would be fairly easy. I only know that it is a blob and that within that blob there should be a Mac address and text in there.

Comment: @JohnMarshall try different encodings from `Charsets` class and maybe one of them will solve the problem.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki can you please look into this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016074/decode-the-blob-using-java