# decode the blob geometry using java

Tags: java, binary, arcgis, spatialite, geopackage

In my table I have two columns, `Data` and `Range`.

Range field is encoded binary from ArcGIS.
this format is supposed to be a standard format with in the Geo spatial industry.

https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/BLOB-Geometry.html

http://www.geopackage.org/spec120/#gpb_format

need to use the `srs_id` to decode the Range field.

```
String sql = "SELECT DATA, RANGE FROM IK_TEMP";

        try (Connection conn = this.connect();
             Statement stmt  = conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery(sql)){

            // loop through the result set
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("DATA") +  "\t" + 
                                   rs.getString("RANGE"));

            }
```

This range field I need to decode.
How can I decode it.

I have seen [example](https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-core-java/blob/master/src/main/java/mil/nga/geopackage/geom/GeoPackageGeometryData.java) but it didn't work.

Comment: What you called "example" is part of a library - you could use the whole library to decode the data.